# How to stop method from stalling out?

Tags: python

So when this method tries to solve a very big problem like 9999^99999^99999 it just stalls out and stops everything else from running, how do I have it so it just ends after, let's say 10 seconds?

```py
def solve_equ(variable, equ):
    ans = []
    if variable is None:
        return [f"`{N(equ)}`"]
    else:
        partial_ans = solve(equ, variable, dict=True)
    for i in partial_ans:
        ans.append(f"{variable} = `{N(list(i.values())[0])}`\n")
    return ans
```

The `solve()` method is the one that stalls out

Comment: Does this post help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477569/python-time-a-method-call-and-stop-it-if-time-is-exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
def solve_equ(variable, equ):
    ans = []
    if variable is None:
        return [f"`{N(equ)}`"]
    else:
        partial_ans = solve(equ, variable, dict=True)
    for i in partial_ans:
        ans.append(f"{variable} = `{N(list(i.values())[0])}`\n")
    return ans

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=solve_equ, name="Solve", args=(x))
proc.start()
time.sleep(10)
proc.terminate()

proc.join()  # cleanup
```

`name` has no effect on the code, it's just for identification.

Comment: Where does `ans` return to?